# customize form_open() to add elements

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2

I using Codelginiter PHP MVC framework to develop a web application, i am trying to use `form_open()` instead of `<form></form>`, what i am trying to do is add `class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search"` to it and seems it doesn't not work.

here is the code to make a form

```
<?php 
echo 
form_open('social_controller/search_me');
?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll quote a section from the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

> Attributes can be added by passing an associative
>   array to the second parameter, like this:

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'email', 'id' => 'myform');
echo form_open('email/send', $attributes);
```

It seems you have not tried adding an associative array as the second parameter? Try this:

```
echo form_open('social_controller/search_me', array(
    'class' => 'navbar-form navbar-left', 
    'role' => 'search'
));
```

Comment: thanks , worked like a charm! documentation has a lot of other fantastic features too,

Answer (score 1):

```
form_open('social_controller/search_me','class="Your Class" role="Your Role" attribute1="value1" attribute2="value2" ');
```